# Splitting data in SQL (separating a string of data)

Tags: sql, validation, split, multiple-columns

I am looking to split up some data in SQL. We currently use databox's in SQL to store data. e.g. the following bit of information would be stored in a databox called: {Script.Details01}.

`{Script.Details01}` = Mr J Bloggs and Miss M Bloggs

What we are trying to do is validate our data, however due to other departments who enter it manually we need to pull through the two names and split them into two different databox's. For example `{Script.Details02}` and `{Script.Details03}.`

Because of the data we need to validate we have tried setting them into cols.

```
"SELECT '{Script.Details01}' as Col1,
'{Script.Details01}' as Col2,
'{Script.Details01}' as Col3"

Col1 Part1 = Item('Col1') Entry(1,'')
```

Is there anyway we can split the data, so that Mr J Bloggs would go into details02 and Miss M Bloggs would go into 03? We can store the data entered and pull it through into questions, messages or ask it to go down a certain route depending on the answer.

Mr J Bloggs   and   Miss M Bloggs
`{Script.Details02}` `{Script.Details03}`

p.s. we do not care about "and" and want everything between this.
If I have confused anyone feel free to let me know and I will try and be clearer :)

Comment: On what criteria would you like the data to be split? E.g if its Mr -> Col 2, if its Miss -> Col 3.

Comment: To be honest I think we just need to split the data first. e.g.
Mr J Bloggs = to go into {Script.Details02}
Miss K Bloggs = to go into {Script.Details03}

These would be pulled through from a view and displayed as e.g. Mr J Bloggs and Miss K Bloggs.

So I think the importance is splitting it first rather than splitting it further into columns?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. This isn't the cleanest, most concise possible way of writing this, and you will need to modify this a bit to work with your table names, intended column names / databoxes etc. but it should give you a good starting point. Bear in mind that if your data entry folks aren't 100% consistent about how they input pairs of names, you're going to run into trouble. You may need to use more sophisticated techniques to clean up the remaining information.

```
 SELECT
 LEFT({Script.Details01}, CHARINDEX(' and ', {Script.Details01})) AS FirstName,
 RIGHT({Script.Details01}, (CHARINDEX(' and ', {Script.Details01}) + 5)) AS SecondName
 FROM MyTable
```

See these articles for more information regarding CharIndex and the Left and Right functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17948.t-sql-right-left-substring-and-charindex-functions.aspx